# "Enforce Data Access in Flow Formulas" not working

Tags: visual-workflow

I have added a custom field named Admin_only__c, which is only visable and editable to the admin.
According to the critical update: having this critical update not enabled, any user (who can access the record) can use the field in a formula of a flow. However this is not true (I created a flow with a formula like: someField = Admin_only__c). So line 3 is not true.

"1. With this update enabled, flow formulas respect the running user’s object permissions, field-level access, and record-level access such as sharing rules.
2. For example, consider an org that makes cases read-only for all users except the case owner.
3. Without this update, when a user who isn’t the case owner runs a flow that accesses a field on a case via a formula, the flow interview ignores record-level security and accesses the field.
4. With this update enabled, the running user’s record-level access is enforced, so that flow interview can’t access the field."

Am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards,
Harry

Comment: Just to point out that I succesfully activated this in early July and tested impacts, and did this again today in a winter'21 sandbox and have the conviction that activating it does not do anything anymore...